# Can't parse a certain field which is within JSON from a webpage using VBA

Tags: json, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to parse property information from [this link](https://torontolife.com/wp-content/themes/sjm-underscores/inc/neighbourhoods/2015/compiled.json) which produces a JSON response. I've used here JSON and VBA converter. However, when I run the script below, I get an error `keyNotFoundError`. I'm trying to parse the value of `properties` which is within `features`.

```
Public Sub parseJson()
    Dim jsonObject As Object, oElem As Variant
    Dim resp$, Url$, R&

    Url = "https://torontolife.com/wp-content/themes/sjm-underscores/inc/neighbourhoods/2015/compiled.json"

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        resp = .responseText
    End With
    
    Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.parseJson(resp)

    For Each oElem In jsonObject("features")
        Debug.Print oElem("properties")
    Next oElem
End Sub
```

I also get the same error when I try to like the following:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim Json As Object
    JsonString = "[{""Entries"":[{""Name"": ""SMTH"",""Gender"": ""Male""}]}]"
    JsonConverter.JsonOptions.AllowUnquotedKeys = True
    Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(JsonString)

    Debug.Print Json(1)("Entries")
End Sub
```

I'm on Windows 7 (32 bit) and I'm using [this library](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON).

One more thing, they are valid JSON and I didn't encounter any error while parsing the same using Python.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the JSON VBA library you're using? Also, if you set a breakpoint within the `For Each`, what does `oElem` look like in the debugger?

Comment: Is it possible that the key includes double-quotes -- `"`?

Comment: Check out the edit @Zev Spitz. FYI, I rectified the quotes this way `resp = Replace(.responseText, """", "'")` but still got the same error.

Comment: If you try to extract the value at `properties` before printing it, do you get the same error? IOW, `Dim x As Variant: x = oElem("properties"): Debug.Print x`.

Comment: RE replacing quotes: I meant that the library has an option for allowing unquoted keys, even though standard JSON requires quotes around the keys. I'm wondering if the `AllowUnquotedKeys` is set to `True`, what happens if the keys are quoted?

Comment: Don't think you can print an entire object. "properties" in you first example is probably a dictionary or a collection, you should try call Print(oElem("properties")("HOOD")) to get the string value. In your second example you are trying to Print an array instead of string values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be failing because `oElem("properties")` is a dictionary. Furthermore, within that dictionary there are a mixture of datatypes associated with the keys so you will need to test the type and handle appropriately. Or use one of the many readily available programs which will handle that and empty the entire json object for you.

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ParseJson()
    Dim jsonObject As Object, oElem As Variant
    Dim resp$, Url$, R&

    Url = "https://torontolife.com/wp-content/themes/sjm-underscores/inc/neighbourhoods/2015/compiled.json"

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        resp = .responseText
    End With
    
    Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(resp)
    
    Dim key As Variant, propertyTypes As Scripting.Dictionary
    
    Set propertyTypes = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    For Each oElem In jsonObject("features")
    
        For Each key In oElem("properties")
           Debug.Print key, vbTab, TypeName(oElem("properties")(key))
           propertyTypes(key) = TypeName(oElem("properties")(key))
        Next

    Next oElem
    'Review propertyTypes dict and/or immediate window print out
    Stop
End Sub
```

Comment: After installing json converter, I could not even execute a single script bypassing this `keyNotFoundError`. When I debug, I could notice that [this line](https://imgur.com/ecDIDwE) in the source code throws that error. Given that your suggested script also encounters that error.

Comment: Unsure. I didn't change the settings regarding unquoted keys and my code above runs just fine. Re-install jsonconverter.bas and also put your json string, returned by .responseText through an online json validator.

Comment: Could you suggest which version [among them](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/releases) should i install and which one between `zip` and `tar.gz`?

Comment: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/master/JsonConverter.bas` - that file. Put it into a standard module called JsonConverter and remove the top line which reads `Attribute VB_Name = "JsonConverter"`  - or simply import the file and that line will be stripped.

Comment: Then go VBE > Tools > References and add a references to Microsoft Scripting Runtime and compile the project to test all ok. You may also need to remove Option Explicit if you already automatically enabled so it doesn't appear twice in module just imported.

Comment: I followed every step very carefully but could not shake off the same error I was having in the first place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229028/discussion-between-qharr-and-smth).

Comment: Hi QHarr, I thought to inform you about the reason why I was having such error `KeyNotFoundError` while running the script. The thing is it is necessary to uncheck the following references (if they are already selected) `Microsoft Internet Controls` and `Selenium Type Library`.

Comment: I have not experienced that. I have had those checked and it has run fine. I think you must have had an odd clash and unsure why.

Comment: @QHarr I have a problem with json response (I got an error dictionary key not found, the error occurs at the level of JSONConverter). Can you join a discussion for 5 minutes?